# Override email templates (mailalert module) in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

We have an eshop in prestashop (1.6.1.12 version) with mail alerts module installed. The concept is to modify the email template in order to change the way some values are being displayed. In particular we would like to modify the new_order email notification (the one that the shop owner receive for every new order) removing the product links from the product list and display the shipping costs without tax (the total tax is visible on the next field of the email).

Answer (score 0):

You have the template files in this directory:

`/modules/mailalerts/mails/[your-language]`